# Execute addClass if element width equals .. pixels

Tags: jquery, css, width, addclass

So I have this search box which shows and hides by changing its width
now I want to add a class to the search icon if its width is larger than zero

```
$("#search input").animate({width: "0px"}, 0);
var searchWidth = $('#search input').width();

$('#search i').click( function() {
    //Change the width (show it)
    var toggleWidth = $("#search input").width() == 150 ? "0px" : "150px";
    $('#search input').animate({ width: toggleWidth });

    //Make the search icon red
    if ( searchWidth > 0 ) {
        $("#search i").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $("#search i").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

now It sorta worked with `toggleClass` but then if you'd click faster than the animation it got messed up, so that's why I tried the above...

```
    //Change the width (show it)
    var toggleWidth = $("#search input").width() == 150 ? "0px" : "150px";
    $('#search input').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    //Make the search icon red
    $("#search i").toggleClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move searchWidth calculation logic below, as you are changing the width on click.

```
$("#search input").animate({width: "0px"}, 0);
//var searchWidth = $('#search input').width();

$('#search i').click( function() {
    //Change the width (show it)
    var toggleWidth = $("#search input").width() == 150 ? "0px" : "150px";
    $('#search input').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
var searchWidth = $('#search input').width();
    //Make the search icon red
    if ( searchWidth > 0 ) {
        $("#search i").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $("#search i").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```